# Pinescript - Days of the week

Tags: pine-script, dayofweek

I can't get the Days of the week to display on Midnight for NY time (utc-4) its only working for UTC, I set it

isMon() =>
dayofweek(time('D',"","America/New_York")) == dayofweek.monday and close ? 1 : 0

drawVerticalLine(offset, cond) =>
if cond
line.new(bar_index[offset], low - LineLength, bar_index[offset], high + LineLength, color=lineColor, width=1, style=line.style_dashed)

drawVerticalLine(0, isMon())

Answer (score 0):

timezone argument can only be used when a session is specified.
but try this, it might work

```
 isMon() => dayofweek(time('D',"","America/New_York"), (utc-4)) == dayofweek.monday and close ? 1 : 0
```

or you just can specify the whole session from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT-1)

You can change timeframe from D to 1 and also compare the day of week 1 min ago
Pinescript takes the time based on the bar open

```
isMon() => dayofweek(time('1',"","America/New_York")) == dayofweek.monday and dayofweek(time('1',"","America/New_York")-1) !=dayofweek(time('1',"","America/New_York")) ? 1 : 0
```

Here is a sample output of the line drawn on monday midnight in UTC-4 timezone

[image]

Comment: Thanks but neither of these solve the issue, I added a couple more lines so you can see what I am trying to do, simply draw a vertical ray at midnight on UTC-4 NY time

Comment: I have updated the answer to draw line at midnight of monday in UTC-4